# Recall is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no true samples

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, cross-validation, k-fold

I am trying to validate my data using Kfold.

```
def printing_kfold_score(X,y):
fold = KFold(5,shuffle=False)
recall_accs=[]

for train_index, test_index in fold.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index,:], X.iloc[test_index,:]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index,:], y.iloc[test_index,:]

    # Call the logistic regression model with a certain C parameter
    lr = LogisticRegression(C = 0.01, penalty = 'l1',solver = 'liblinear')
    # Use the training data to fit the model. In this case, we use the portion of the fold to train the model
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())

    # Predict values using the test indices in the training data
    y_pred_undersample = lr.predict(X_test)

    # Calculate the recall score and append it to a list for recall scores representing the current c_parameter
    recall_acc = recall_score(y_test,y_pred_undersample)
    recall_accs.append(recall_acc)
print(np.mean(recall_accs))

printing_kfold_score(X_undersample,y_undersample)
```

X_undersample is a dataframe (984,29)

y_undersample is a dataframe (984,1)

I am getting the below Warning:

```
0.5349321454470113
C:\Users\sudha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1272: UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no true samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
C:\Users\sudha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1272: UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no true samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
```

Why am I getting this warning, my data is perfectly balanced(50/50) this warning and low recall score wasn't expected.Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

I tried printing the value shape and value of x_test and y_test.

```
   x_train shape (788, 29) 
   x_test shape (196, 29) 
   y_train shape (788, 1) 
   y_test shape (196, 1) 

 x_test      V1        V2        V3  ...       V27       V28     normAmount
    541  -2.312227  1.951992 -1.609851  ...  0.261145 -0.143276   -0.353229
    623  -3.043541 -3.157307  1.088463  ... -0.252773  0.035764    1.761758
    4920 -2.303350  1.759247 -0.359745  ...  0.039566 -0.153029    0.606031

y_test         Class
38042       0
170554      0
16019       0
```

Is it because of the first column which represents index?

Comment: "*I am unable to get the desired output*" is not helpful; what *exactly* is your issue and your question?

Comment: Where exactly (which command)? Please edit & update the question with the full error trace.

Comment: It could be `y_test`, in one of your folds, has no positive cases – especially with a sample of only 984 records. Although if the dependent variable is truly balanced 50-50, that may be unlikely.

Comment: @blacksite, I have updated the question with my train and test shape. also I have printed the value of y_test and x_test. Is it because of the first column of my df which is index value?

Comment: @AMITBISHT, this is a binary classification model, right? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but `y_test` in your DataFrame seems to be an index, where `Class` seems (although we only see 0s here) binary. Can you provide the counts of each value by class for the predicted and actual class vectors?

Comment: @blacksite, hi,it is a binary classification.`y_pred_undersample [0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1]` and  y_test changes, sometimes it is all 0,sometimes 1,etc.

Comment: @blacksite, I also tried with kfold=2. And I got below error,and I think you are right.
`ValueError: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 0`

Answer (score 1):

You described the issue in your comment:

> `y_test` changes – sometimes it is all 0, sometimes 1, etc.

This is effectively what's happening:

```py
>>> from sklearn.metrics import *
>>> recall_score([0,0], [1,0])
```

> UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no true samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
>     _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))

You should take steps to ensure `y_test` always has positive and negative samples available so you can more accurately assess the performance of your classifier.

Comment: I resolved the error, I just simply turned shuffle = True in fold() function. But, still not clear how it affects the KFold, because my test set is always different in a fold.